# The result is not showed in the result field

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, web

I made a web-application prototype using flask framework that consists of a text input of two int values, following by a choice of an operation, and  the result field. You type a number in the  two input fields, choose the operation and get the result, pretty simple, because i'm just beggining at it.

[the result field is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvvLu.png)
the result should be shown

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block h1 %}
<h1 style="font-family: sans-serif">a sum</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block style %}
<style>
    input:out-of-range {
        color: red;
    }

    select, input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input::placeholder {
        color: gray;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .error-background {
        background-color: #ffcccc; /* Light red color */
    }

    .error-message {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="">
    <label for="first_number"><strong>Number 1:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="f_number" id="first_number" placeholder="integer here"><br>
    <label for="second_number"><strong>Number 2:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="s_number" id="second_number" placeholder="integer here"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="subtraction" name="conta_mat" value="subtraction">
    <label for="subtraction">Subtraction</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="addition" name="conta_mat" value="addition">
    <label for="addition">Addition</label><br>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Result:</strong>&nbsp;<strong><span id="Result"></span></strong></p>
    <p class="error-message" id="error_message"></p>
</form><br>
{% endblock %}
```

that's the html

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const firstNumberInput = document.getElementById('first_number');
    const secondNumberInput = document.getElementById('second_number');
    const resultElement = document.getElementById('result');
    const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error_message');

    firstNumberInput.addEventListener('input', calculateResult);
    secondNumberInput.addEventListener('input', calculateResult);

    function calculateResult() {
        const firstValue = parseInt(firstNumberInput.value);
        const secondValue = parseInt(secondNumberInput.value);
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="conta_mat"]');

        if (!isNaN(firstValue + secondValue)) {

                for (const button of buttons) {
                    if (button.checked) {
                        if (button.value === 'subtraction') {
                            resultElement.innerText = `${firstValue - secondValue}`;

                        } else if (button.value === 'addition') {
                            resultElement.innerText = `${firstValue + secondValue}`;
                        }
                        errorMessage.textContent = '';
                    }
                }
        } else {
            resultElement.textContent = '';
            errorMessage.textContent = 'Please enter valid numbers and select an operation.';
        }
    }
});
```

that's the script

how do i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Because "Result" is case-sensitive ...
`span id="Result"`
`document.getElementById('result')`

```js
var firstNumberInput = 0;
var secondNumberInput = 0;
var resultElement = "";
var errorMessage = "";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    firstNumberInput = document.getElementById('first_number');
    secondNumberInput = document.getElementById('second_number');
    resultElement = document.getElementById('Result');
    errorMessage = document.getElementById('error_message');

    firstNumberInput.addEventListener('input', calculateResult);
    secondNumberInput.addEventListener('input', calculateResult);
});
function calculateResult() {
        const firstValue = parseInt(firstNumberInput.value);
        const secondValue = parseInt(secondNumberInput.value);
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="conta_mat"]');

        if (!isNaN(firstValue + secondValue)) {

                for (const button of buttons) {
                    if (button.checked) {
                        if (button.value === 'subtraction') {
                            resultElement.innerText = firstValue - secondValue;

                        } else if (button.value === 'addition') {
                            resultElement.innerText = firstValue + secondValue;
                        }
                        errorMessage.textContent = '';
                    }
                }
        } else {
            resultElement.textContent = '';
            errorMessage.textContent = 'Please enter valid numbers and select an operation.';
        }
}
```

```html
<style>
    input:out-of-range {
        color: red;
    }

    select, input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input::placeholder {
        color: gray;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .error-background {
        background-color: #ffcccc; /* Light red color */
    }

    .error-message {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<h1 style="font-family: sans-serif">a sum</h1>
<form action="">
    <label for="first_number"><strong>Number 1:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="f_number" id="first_number" placeholder="integer here"><br>
    <label for="second_number"><strong>Number 2:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="s_number" id="second_number" placeholder="integer here"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="subtraction" name="conta_mat" value="subtraction" onChange="calculateResult()">
    <label for="subtraction">Subtraction</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="addition" name="conta_mat" value="addition" onChange="calculateResult()">
    <label for="addition">Addition</label><br>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Result:</strong>&nbsp;<strong><span id="Result"></span></strong></p>
    <p class="error-message" id="error_message"></p>
</form><br>
```